# REFS Dedup from Server 2019 to Windows 11 Pro does not work

Tags: storage, windows-server-2019, windows-11, refs

On a Windows Server 2019, I have a storage spaces mirror with REFS dedup volume. I connected all of the drives that are a part of the storage spaces mirror to a Windows 11 Pro device. Everything is seen as it should be except it cannot copy any of the files off without error. I then connected it back to the Windows Server, and the storage space is seen but the volume is seen listed as raw. Running refsutils does see it but fsutils does not see it as refs.

I’m trying to understand what Windows 11 Pro would have done to the volume to cause it to no longer be readable on Server 2019 so that I can start working to find a fix.